# PHP and MYSQLI Error, Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting the Call to a member function query() on a non-object when I try to call my function.

My code looks like this:

```
function add_profile() {

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "username";
    $dbname = "dbname";
    $dbpassword = "password";
    $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname); 
    if (!$link) { 
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO payment_profiles(id, client_id) VALUES ( '','$profile_id')"; 

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!result) 
    { 
    echo 'Error: ', $mysqli->error;
    }
}

add_profile();
```

It says my error is on the line: `$result = $mysqli->query($sql);`

I'm assuming I'm not calling something properly. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Where is `$mysqli`defined?

Comment: I just had the same error because my password was wrong ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code you're mixing both procedural and object-oriented code. Choose either one or the other. Here's how you would solve the problem the procedural way.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)
```

---

> I'm getting the Call to a member function query() on a non-object when
>   I try to call my function.

That's because the `$mysqli` object is not declared anywhere (or is it)? Before you can use `$mysqli` you should first create an instance of `mysqli` and assign it to your object.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");
```

Only then you may call the methods of the mysqli class like `$mysqli->query();`

The error you made depends probably on two misconceptions:

1) you pasted half of your code from the procedural-style part of the mysqli manual and half from the oop part

2) you assume `$mysqli` is a global object instantiated with `$mysqli_connect();`. It is not. You should invoke the constructor with the `new` keyword if you'd like to use it as an object.

Comment: Worked like a charm $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname); 
 /////

 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
           ///////
```